# Low inbound connections and fixed getnetworkinfo score at 4

Tags: network, bitcoin-cli, tor

I spent hours researching for possible solutions, but couldn't find any. I set up my RPi4 bitcoin node about a month ago. It communicates through Tor (see torrc content).

```
SOCKSPort 9050
Log notice stdout
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/lnd/
HiddenServicePort 8080 127.0.0.1:8080
```

It took a while to sync the whole network (almost two weeks) and since then I noticed that the number of inbound connection was near to 0 or low (max was around 12 and 5 on average).
In addition, the score value returned by `bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo` is still 4 and unchanged since the beginning.
I'm wondering what might be causing this issue and how to solve.
Here the bitcoin.conf, which I think is pretty standard:

```
#adjust memory usage
dbcache=2000

#transaction validity
assumevalid=0

#settings
rpcuser=[redacted]
rpcpassword=[redacted]
rpcbind=192.168.1.x
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcport=8332

#server settings
#listen=1
server=1

#transaction index
txindex=1

# Allows LND & Bitcoin Core to communicate via ZeroMQ
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:28332
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:28333

## Tor Settings
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
debug=tor
onlynet=onion
bind=127.0.0.1
dnsseed=0
dns=0
```

I've tried to play around with some settings unsuccessfully and ended up reinstalling tor.
Regarding the firewall: I opened and mapped the following ports: 8332,8333, 18333, 28332, 28333 and then for lightning 10009 and 8080.
When opening and forwarding port 9050 and 9051 I observed no improvement.

getnetworkinfo output:

```
[
    {
        "version": 210100,
        "subversion": "/Satoshi:0.21.1/",
        "protocolversion": 70016,
        "localservices": "0000000000000409",
        "localservicesnames": [
            "NETWORK",
            "WITNESS",
            "NETWORK_LIMITED"
        ],
        "localrelay": true,
        "timeoffset": -3,
        "networkactive": true,
        "connections": 10,
        "connections_in": 0,
        "connections_out": 10,
        "networks": [
            {
                "name": "ipv4",
                "limited": true,
                "reachable": false,
                "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
                "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
            },
            {
                "name": "ipv6",
                "limited": true,
                "reachable": false,
                "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
                "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
            },
            {
                "name": "onion",
                "limited": false,
                "reachable": true,
                "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
                "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
            }
        ],
        "relayfee": 0.00001,
        "incrementalfee": 0.00001,
        "localaddresses": [
            {
                "address": "[redacted].onion",
                "port": 8333,
                "score": 4
            }
        ],
        "warnings": ""
    }
]
```

I'd be happy to provide more information and thank you in advance for your time.

EDIT: I've done more research:

While using Tor, it's pointless to open ports on router side. Tor handles all the request over the onion service. I tested this and even with closed port, bitcoind was connecting to Outbound peers fine. I get a few inbound connections as well, but the score didn't improve.

So I went into the source code and found out why the default score was 4.
[Here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net.cpp) the link to Github.
I believe (and might be wrong so please help!) that the following functions are responsible for setting the `nScore` value:

1. `GetLocalAddrForPeer(CNode *pnode)` which return 3 if `GetnScore(addrLocal) > LOCAL_MANUAL`
2. `AddLocal(const CService& addr, int nScore)` which adds a 1 to `nScore` if `!fAlready || nScore >= info.nScore`

This yields a 4 and it might make sense. Now, I suppose the function responsible for updating the `nScore` is the following:

```
bool SeenLocal(const CService& addr)
{
    {
        LOCK(cs_mapLocalHost);
        if (mapLocalHost.count(addr) == 0)
            return false;
        mapLocalHost[addr].nScore++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and here I get totally lost, but I guess that mapLocalHost.count(addr) must always be 0 in my case. My knowledge of C++ reaches this point, so the additional question is what changes mapLocalHost and why doesn't it update when a new peer is added on my machine?